# What is the function of 'Multiple Values' in Additional Fields in the Catalog Field Mapping?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

When I go to Admin-> Catalog then select the Catalog and go to Field Mapping.
Under Additional Fields, there is a checkbox option: 'Multiple Values'
What is the function of this 'Multiple Values' checkbox?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can multiple values in one field. For example if a product has some keywords attached to it you would normally use multiple values to describe all of these values.

Inside the product catalog you store these multiple values by ~. If your product 12345 would have the keywords red, blue, design. Your column "keywords" would look like `red~blue~design`. If you then check the multiple value column you can for example exclude products that have the keyword "red". Or boost products that have the keyword "design" or whatever use case you might have.

For example you could have the country codes stored in a column named CountryAvailability and store something like "`USA~GER~FRA~BRA`". And then you would use the users attribute or the store to make the rules only show the products that are available in that country.